# Print sequence of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm sure this is quite a simple programming question however, I cant seem to understand it...

I'm trying to make the console.log print out numbers like this - 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 - one for each line. I thought modulo could be used to make this happen, however, I cant seem to figure out how to use it.

Here is the code:

```
iteration = 16;

for (var i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
    if(i == iteration%4 )
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the formatted output you expect? It's not clear (at least to me), where you expect the linebreaks.

Comment: use another for loop. nest this within the new loop. and make a line break in the outer loop using "\n"

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "one for each line." As @Mureinik said, please show what you mean in a well-formatted way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a single loop.

No, you do not need the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder). This would give you

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 ...
```

But instead you could divide the actual value by `4` and take the integer value for `console.log`.

```js
const iteration = 16;

for (let i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
    console.log(Math.floor(i / 4) + 1); // offset for starting with 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use two nested for loops, one for the rows and another one for the columns.

Here's an example of how i would do it:

```
const columns = 4;
const rows = 4;

//if you want to just console.log each number on a different line
for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log("\n");
}

//if you want to add each number to an array, and then log the array
for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  let columnsArray = [];
  columnsArray.length = columns;
  columnsArray.fill(i);
  console.log(columnsArray);
}

//if you want to just log the numbers, you can spread the array
for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  let columnsArray = [];
  columnsArray.length = columns;
  columnsArray.fill(i);
  console.log(...columnsArray);
}

//or you could push the arrays in another one, and get a matrix!
const matrix = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  let columnsArray = [];
  columnsArray.length = columns;
  columnsArray.fill(i);
  matrix.push(columnsArray);
}
console.log(matrix);
```

It was not clear the output that you wanted, so i got a little sidetracked and made an example for the different cases that came to my mind.